# Updating class of list item - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Pretty simple problem but it's been bugging me for almost an hour now. Basically, I want to update list classes onClick, then remove the class again when another item is clicked.

```
 <nav>
   <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
     <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
       <li class="current-menu-item">
         <a class="scroll" href="#top"><span>Home</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="">
         <a class="scroll" href="#featured_work_anchor"><span>Featured Work</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="">
         <a class="scroll" href="#about_contact_anchor"><span>About/Contact</span></a>
       </li>               
     </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu-main-menu li').on('click', changeClass);
});

function changeClass() {
    $('#menu-main-menu li').removeClass('current-menu-item');
    $(this).addClass('current-menu-item');
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mw5sgcLn/2/), ready to go. I appreciate any help. Perhaps I'm approaching the problem wrong or maybe missing something silly ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mw5sgcLn/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem I could see is the `removeClass()` function, either don't pass any argument so that all the classes in the `li` are removed or pass the class names to be removed.

```
function changeClass() {
    $('#menu-main-menu li').removeClass('current-menu-item');
    $(this).addClass('current-menu-item');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L9het95c/)(Also in the fiddle you forgot to include jQuery)

Comment: +1 good answer, though writing a `changeClass()` function is kind of superfluous. You could just throw that right into the click event - unless the asker intends to call that function outside of people clicking an `li`.

Comment: In the OP fiddle there's removeClass('') which is key problem should be just removeClass();

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the element that is being set as current:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-main-menu li').on('click', function(){
    changeClass($(this));
  });
});

function changeClass(element) {
  $('#menu-main-menu li').removeClass('current-menu-item');
  element.addClass('current-menu-item');
}
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mw5sgcLn/4/